# How to display an error message in laravel if the same file name is uploaded twice

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

Errors are not being displayed on the user interface, instead the whoops error is popping up.

I have tried to call the error messages in the blade view.

```
@if ($errors->has('file'))
            <span class="red-text"><strong>{{ $errors->first('file') }} 
</strong></span>
  @endif
```

I want it to display a message in the view saying that "The file has already been uploaded, please upload a different one"

Comment: Well it depends a lot on how you define the term "same file". Same contents? ..Same checksum? or Same name?

Comment: by the same name

Comment: When you say the laravel error is popping up, what do you mean by that? A whoops error? Also, checking just on file name is not a great way of determining if the same file is being uploaded twice, unless you really don't care much about the contents and are just doing a sanity check.

Comment: yes the whoops error. For now that is the only way i know how to do it but enlighten me on how i can check the contents.

Comment: @KayC I guess you are storing the filename in db then before each upload run a select query to see if the filename exists in db if so just skip the upload and show error message.